# UITextField add cleared icon

Tags: ios, objective-c

For a `UITextField` in an iOS app, is there a way to add an `x` to clear the contents of the text field? How would I do this?

```
CGRect textFieldRect = CGRectMake(40, 70, 240, 30);
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:textFieldRect];
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
// add a clear button?
```

Comment: A little x icon will appear automatically once you enter at least one character. Are you not seeing it?

Comment: No I don't see anything when I type in the textfield.

Comment: Oh yeah, you need to set the `clearButtonMode` property.